# SUM(subquery) in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, subquery, aggregation

Basically, I am trying the following:

```
SELECT m.col1, SUM(SELECT col5 FROM table WHERE col2 = m.col1)
FROM table AS m
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Why don't you do this:

```
SELECT m.col1, (SELECT SUM(col5) FROM table WHERE col2 = m.col1)
FROM table AS m
```

Answer (score 5):

yes - use joins

```
SELECT m.col1, SUM(j.col5) FROM table AS m 
       JOIN table AS j ON j.col2 = m.col1 GROUP BY m.col1
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to enclose the subquery in additional parentheses

```
SELECT m.col1, SUM((SELECT col5 FROM table WHERE col2 = m.col1))
FROM table AS m
```

In my case this solved it.

Also the MySQL documentation (13.2.15 Subqueries) says:

> A subquery must always appear within parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Sum is used inside the second select, where we want to sum the column.
The col2 may be ambiguous column, if such column exists in the table m.

```
SELECT
    m.col1,
    (SELECT SUM(t.col5) FROM table AS t WHERE t.col2 = m.col1) AS sumcol
FROM table AS m
```