# MySql SUM (subquery)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select the sum of a mono-field subquery but I can't find any good syntax.

Solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757061/sumsubquery-in-mysql) won't works for me because my subquery needs a GROUP BY to avoid duplicate entries.

Here is the subquery (simplified cause it's long):

```
SELECT montant FROM table1 
JOIN flag ON table1.flag = flag.id
JOIN historique ON historique.bu_id = flag.bu_id 
WHERE historique.com_id = '144'
AND table1.date > '$aDate' AND table1.date_end < '$anotherDate'
GROUP BY table1.id
```

What I want is:

```
SELECT SUM(Subquery) AS Total
```

But it does not works as is, and if I do not use the GROUP BY statement it counts  table1.montant multiple times

EDIT: Here is a screen capture of the complete subquery with a COUNT(id) to show you what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Please show subquery.

Comment: It is the first query

Comment: **Please** include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: So you are trying to sum all returned values? What's wrong with `SELECT SUM(montant)...`?

Comment: I'm trying to sum all results of subquery. The group by is here cause the JOINs makes the subquery return multiple times each "montant", so the SUM would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you need  a global sum you should use just

```
SELECT sum(montant) FROM table1 
JOIN flag ON table1.flag = flag.id
JOIN historique ON historique.bu_id = flag.bu_id 
WHERE historique.com_id = '144'
AND table1.date > '$aDate' AND table1.date_end < '$anotherDate'
```

avoiding group by

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: My JOINs conditions where not good, I needed to add a comparison between table1 and historique. Now there are no duplicated rows