# MYSQL Multiple Tables Join

Tags: mysql, database, join, where-clause

I have multiple tables in my project and I want to count out something from a table which is video table , first let me attach the table Images...

[image]

above is table_std

[image]

above is tablesubject

[image]

above is table_chapter

[image]

above is table video

now I want to fund total sum of videotime which is in the tbvid and want it against stdid like below
[image]

so here first it all starts with standard table , next table subtable is dependent of std table then chap table is depends over sub table and vid table depends over chap table.

for me the sql query is going to be very difficult if anyone can help me with this , it will be so appreciated !

Comment: Do **not**, **never**, **never ever** post images of tables. Post the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text**.

Comment: You have a chronic abbreviation problem. "vidtime" instead of "video_time", "subdesc" insteand of "subject_description". I still cannot work out what "std" stands for. Is it "standard" or "student"? Who knows? You may think this kind of abbreviations make your code look cool, but in the end you just make it difficult to read.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this is just for an example , std stands for standard here !

Comment: @stickybit images helps to understand everything very fast and easily

Comment: @NisargJani: Images aren't (easily) consumable and therefore make it needlessly hard for people to built up test environments to work on *your* problem. Make it as easy as possible for those people and use proper DDL and DML -- help those who help you -- don't use images!

Comment: Nisarg Jani as @sticky bit mentioned before posting images instead of text makes people wasting a lot of time doing examples and tests for your problem. In my opinion it is pointless answering a question that doesn't provide minimal effort to at least making  the question easier to  reproduce in a test environment. It will take maybe more than 20 minutes only creating the tables . Copy paste needs only some seconds.Help us to help you.

Comment: Examples also need to be comprehensible and usable. Also, "it's just an example", and "I'll do it correct later", are some of the most frequent excuses we hear here. Sorry to be so tough on you, we mean well, I hope you can understand that. My advice is: Delete this question, and start again, this time without the images, and with your own best attempt at solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Refer from
[SUM(subquery) in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757061/sumsubquery-in-mysql)

```sql
SELECT `std`.*,
    (SELECT SUM(`video`.`vidtime`) FROM `video` WHERE `vidid` = `std`.`stdid`) AS `sum_vidtime`
FROM `table_std` AS `std`
```

If you want to use only these columns: `stdid`, `vidtime` (`sum_vidtime` in my case) then it is no need to join multiple tables. Use sub query.

And as everyone said, please don't use image for an example.

Comment: ok I tried but in my case there are 4 tables , each table depends on another for me it didn't work !

Comment: In that case do like every one said, post `CREATE` and `INSERT` for example code. Or delete this question and start again with **text** not **image** as @KIKO commented.